# Having trouble getting a vertical detection of connect 4 win

Tags: java, arrays

Right now I have a school assignment where I have to create a connect 4 game in java without a gui using arrays. So far I have been able to get the game to detect a horizontal four in a row but I can't seem to get a vertical four in a row. Originally my array was a 6x7 but I have changed it to a 5x5 just to test the concept of swapping the arrays dementions. Just to make less clutter, I only included the part of the code with the vertical detection.

```
for (column = 0; column < board.length; column++) {

            count_piece = 0;
            max = 0;
            for (row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
                if (max < count_piece) {
                    max = count_piece;
                }
                if (board[column][row] == 'X') {
                    count_piece++;
                } else {
                    count_piece = 0;
                }

            }

        }
        System.out.println(max);
        if (max == 4) {
            System.out.println("\nYou Win!");
            break;
        }
```

If you need more information or if anything is not clear please let me know and i'll be glad to provide some more info.

EDIT:
Here is the one with the inverted loop.

```
for (row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
        count_piece = 0;
        max = 0;
        for (column = 0; column < board.length; column++) {

            if (max < count_piece) {
                max = count_piece;
            }
            if (board[column][row] == 'X') {
                count_piece++;
            } else {
                count_piece = 0;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: max seems to be redundant to me.  you could just increment count_piece as you go, and as soon as you get to 4 (or whatever the specified number in a row you need) just break out of the loops

Comment: I used to experience "array dementions" when I was learning to program (too long ago).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about inverting your loop that way your inner loop changing will be the column instead of the row?

Also make your inner loop take the length of the single array you are in.

So instead of using `board.length` use something like  `board[i].length`

**Edit**

I think your logic inside your inner loop is wrong...

Try this:

```
if (board[row][column] == 'X') {
    count_piece++;
    if(count_piece == 4) {
        System.out.println("you win");
        return;
    }
} else {
    count_piece = 0;
}
```

Here is both checks Horizontal and Vertical with any size array

```
int count_piece = 0;

        //Checking Vertical Win
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            count_piece = 0;
            for (int column = 0; column < board[row].length; column++) {

                if (board[row][column] == 'X') {
                    count_piece++;
                    if (count_piece == 4) {
                        System.out.println("you win");
                        return;
                    }

                } else {
                    count_piece = 0;
                }


            }
        }

        //Checking Horizontal Win
        for (int column = 0; column < board.length; column++) {
            count_piece = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < board[column].length; row++) {

                if (board[row][column] == 'X') {
                    count_piece++;
                    if (count_piece == 4) {
                        System.out.println("you win");
                        return;
                    }

                } else {
                    count_piece = 0;
                }


            }
        }
```

Comment: Will this solution work on the 6x7 array? Or will it only work on the temporary 5x5 I created?

Comment: I don't see why It will matter what kind of array is... as long as your limit accordingly in the specific loops.

Comment: Tried it and it did not work. I'll post an edit with the changes.

Comment: Still having some issues. Let me comment out the horizontal code. Still did not work.

Comment: You helped provide the general template to complete it. All I had to do is reverse the array dimensions. So i'll still give you a check.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see is assigning max before incrementing count_piece (meaning you would have to get 5 in a row).
Also as others have said length might have issue (not familiar with java so you might get away with it as length would either be 5 or 25 depending if it takes all indices or just the first columns indices.  regardless when you go back to 6x7 it will break.
Also what your code is currently doing is going through each column and checking if the row has 4 in a row.  What you want is to check for 4 in a row on both axis (my solution would be to have a row count variable and a column count variable (unless you need diagonal)).
adding 
count_piece_Col=0; max=0;
above the first for loop and incrementing it similarly to the row count

*lazy way

```
    for(column=0;column<board.length;column++)   
            {
                count_piece=0; max_r=0;
                for(row=0;row<board.length;row++)
                {

                if(max_r<count_piece) 
                    {
                        max_r=count_piece;
                    }
                    if(board[column][row]=='X')
                    {
                        count_piece++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count_piece=0;
                    }

            }

        }   
    for(row=0;row<board.length;row++)   
            {
                count_piece=0; max_c=0;
                for(column=0;column<board.length;column++)
                {

                if(max_c<count_piece) 
                    {
                        max_c=count_piece;
                    }
                    if(board[column][row]=='X')
                    {
                        count_piece++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count_piece=0;
                    }

            }

        }
```

Comment: But when doing it vertically it does not count at all